# Changing TextBlock color from cs (windows phone 7)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, textblock

I am completely new developer at Windows Phone 7. I have `TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDate}` on MainPage.xaml page.

How can I change color of this TextBlock from MainPage.xaml.cs?

Comment: Please edit this question to provide more of the relevant details, such as the fact that the TextBlock is in a DataTemplate. Showing some representative XAML would help us help you better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you need to give the `TextBlock` element an `x:Name` attribute, e.g. `x:Name="myTextBlock"`.  Once you've done this, the TextBlock is available in the code-behind as a field with the same name as what you put in the `x:Name`.

To set the foreground color of a TextBlock, you can use something like

```
myTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(someColor);
```

Comment: I have this: "Error 1 The name 'myTextBlock' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @Karloss: Since you haven't provided all of your MainPage.xaml, I'm going to guess that either you haven't given the TextBlock an `x:Name="myTextBlock"` attribute, or your TextBlock lies within a `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Yes, my TextBlock lies in DataTemplate. How can i access it?

Comment: @Karloss: please edit your question to include (a) your full MainPage.xaml, and (b) why you want to set the colour of a TextBlock from codebehind.  You're already binding to the Text of the TextBlock, can you not use a binding for the Foreground as well?

Comment: Thanks for ideas. I have binded Color within other data.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<Grid  Background="Yellow" >  
    <TextBlock Foreground="Blue"
               Height="20"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               Margin="0" 
               Text="this is a test"/> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: I need to change color from cs file depending on logic (some fields will have red color, other black ones)

Comment: yet logic is simple.then change background color of Grid by cs file for respective textblock as textblock has no background property,and thats why we put Grid.

Comment: set name property of Grid and then set backround.

Answer (score 0):

As your TextBlock is in a DataTemplate it will [probably] be binding to an item in a collection. This means if you bind the color to a property you will need that property in the item class and not in your main page. If you want different items to be different colors then you will need to add a property to the item class. If you already have a property that isn't the correct type (Brush) then you can use a converter on the binding to avoid adding an unnecessary property.

If you don't want to add the property to your item class then the best option is to declare multiple DataTemplates in the pages Resources and then swap the templates as you need:

```
something.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["BlueItemTemplate"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Go in the properties in xaml and add

```
Foreground="Red"
```